# Asset tag on grails 2.4.0

Tags: grails

I started a new grails project on version 2.4.0.
In this version, subfolder asset has been added in to grails-app folder, in order to easy access js, css, images, etc.

However, i can't access to subfolder, for example, i got folder structure like this:

`grails-app/assets/stylesheets/fonts/font.css`

Then when I use 
`<asset:stylesheet src="font.css"/>` (note that font.css was put in stylesheets folder)

But when I tried this, font.css not found.

```
<asset:stylesheet src="/fonts/font.css"/>
```

Please suggest another way to access subfolder using asset tag.

Comment: How does your stylesheet header looks like? does it include `= require self`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The approach you're taking *should* work. I just tested as vanilla 2.4.0 project and only added the tags above - it worked fine on OSX. The only thing I can see that's not completely standard is that you don't need the leading `/` before `fonts/font.css`.

I'd try removing that, and just double-check there isn't a typo anywhere. You can also use the console (which will complain about missing assets) and the Chrome Developer Tools to debug the address it's requesting (in the Network tab you should see the asset with a 404 error).

Answer (score 1):

Don't directly link to a sub folder. Use `application.css` in `grails-app/assets/stylesheets`.

Within the `application.css` tell the Asset plugin to include your `font.css` by adding the following:

```
/*
* This is a manifest file that'll be compiled into application.css, which will include all the files
* listed below.
*
* Any CSS file within this directory can be referenced here using a relative path.
*
* You're free to add application-wide styles to this file and they'll appear at the top of the
* compiled file, but it's generally better to create a new file per style scope.
*
*= require fonts/font.css
*= require self
*/
```

Within your layout (GSP) use then the `application.css` like this.

```
<asset:stylesheet src="application.css"/>
```

This will solve your issue.

Comment: While it is often a good idea to do the aggregation of your styles as you mention, the approach the OP is taking is valid and *should* yield a CSS file in the client. It is often overkill to include all your CSS on every page, so loading modules where needed is a sensible approach. IMHO if you want to do aggregation of CSS and split it up you're already in dire need of SASS or LESS anyway ;)

Comment: Well, does it need a sub folder like stylesheets/fonts/font.css ? I tried solution above but it doesn't work.